# Android listview change image in row

Tags: android, listview, imageview, row, multi-select

Hello i'm working on an app where i'm basically just making a custom multi select listview i did something like this LeftAL is just an array list and this code below is in my onClick

```
if(LeftAL.contains(position)){
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkboxoff);
   int i = position;
   Integer intObj = new Integer(i);
   LeftAL.remove(intObj);
}else{
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);
   LeftAL.add(position);
}
```

and then checkboxoff looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"    
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_pressed_off" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off" />
</selector>
```

and checkbox on is the same thing basically just different images

Now that all works fine as it should and i didn't actually notice this for a little while but when i check say item 3 in my list. It checks and adds to the array list as it should however if i scroll down to the next group of list items i will see that number 3 of the second set is also checked for instance lets just say for example only 3 rows show on my phone.

```
Cat
Dog
Egg
-------off screen-----
Fox
Gerbil
Hog
```

I check Dog then i scroll gerbil would also be checked i guess this is just android like recycling or something but it's definately an issue how can i fix this so that only 3 in the list checks not 3 in the next set as well.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android absolutely recycles the `View`s in a `ListView`.  What you need to do is ensure that you are storing the checked / unchecked state in a separate list and set the state of the check box accordingly each time it's shown.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on what you mean by storing the checked / unchecked state in another list are you talking a list array? And then how should i know if its shown or not? Thank you for the answer

Comment: You need to make another ArrayList that just contains the checked state and set correct entry there when the user clicks the check box in one of your rows.  Then in your ListAdapter you can look into that ArrayList and see if the box should be checked or not.  You can't rely on the UI element to hold that since it's being recycled.